# c++ virtual method isn't being called

Tags: c++, virtual

I have two c++ classes declared in headers. The base declares a virtual method and the second class overrides it. The implementations are in .cpp files.

The code is fairly simple

```
void DefendProperty::apply(Queue<Defend*>* defendQueue, 
const Tool* toolSource, const Actor* actorSource, const Actor* defender) {
    cout << "BASE" << endl;
}
```

---

```
void DefendPropertyPhysical::apply(Queue<Defend*>* defendQueue, 
Tool* toolSource, const Actor* actorSource, const Actor* defender) {
    cout << "CORRECT" << endl;
    defendQueue->enqueue(new Defend(
        DefendTypePhysical::TYPE, 
        new DamageValuesPhysical(
        getRandomDouble(minDamageReduction, maxDamageReduction))
    ));
}
```

The point is that when I call the class instantiated as B, it outputs BASE, not CORRECT. I have no idea what's going on at this point.

The classes are stored in a base ToolProperty type that doesn't have the apply method. When they are called, they are typecasted into the DefendProperty type using dynamic_cast.

```
dynamic_cast<DamageProperty*>(node->value)->apply(damageQueue, toolSource, actorSource);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is going to be very tricky to answer without seeing a complete compilable test-case (http://sscce.org).  (Oh, apparently people have spotted the problem.  But in future, please consider making a simple test case before posting.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the method in the derived class is different of the one in the base class. (One takes a `const Tool*`, the other a non-const `Tool*`)

Because of the different signature the method of the derived class doesn't override the method of the base class, but instead declares a new, unrelated method.

Comment: Not totally unrelated.  One overloads the other.  Without a using declaration it will hide the other.  WITH a using declaration he could run afoul of ambiguity errors.

Comment: omgz, nice eye. I totally didn't see that o-o. Crazy long sig. It was actually not storing a variable and throwing out whacked data as well (reading wrong places in the heap???). I tried doing like x = 3 and x was 0ccccccccc in a totally unrelated method ^_^. *EDIT* now that I'm looking at the code on overflow, it's easy to see. In VS, it was just one long crazy line >.<.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions have different signatures.  Look at the type for "toolSource".  Your second is not an override of the first, but an overload.

Common mistake that the compiler will almost never warn you about.  I don't know of one that does anyway.

BTW, there's no reason to use dynamic cast if you're going to use it on a pointer and not check the result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the function signatures are the same. `toolSource` isn't const in `DefendPropertyPhysical`. If the signatures don't match up, the c++ compiler will not assume that you made a mistake, it will just assume that you're declaring a new overload of that method. [C++11's explicit override](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicit_overrides_and_final) helps with this.
2. Make sure `DefendProperty::apply` is marked as `virtual` in the header.